# What is the set-like data structure in c++

Tags: c++, delphi, data-structures, set

I need to use the advantages of delphi sets like "in" in c++, but I don't know if there is a data structure like sets in c++

I know that I may use an array instead, but as  I have said I want to use sets advantages like "in", so is there any built in data structure like sets in c++?

If yes, please explain how to use it, I'm still a starter in c++

If no, is there any way to represent it (exept array since I know it).

thanks in advance :)

Comment: [`std::set`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html) is a set. You can `#include <set>` to get it.

Comment: "set of" and its native operators (in, +, -, *) are peculiar to Pascal (and Delphi). C++ implements something alike using templates, but they lack the elegance of the Pascal implementation (although right now Pascal sets are limited to 255 elements)

Comment: @ldsandon: 256 elements - 0..255. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a standard library container called `std::set`... I don't know delphi, but a simple *element in set* operation would be implemented by using the `find` method and comparing the result with `end`:

```
std::set<int> s;
s.insert( 5 );
if ( s.find( 5 ) != s.end() ) {
   // 5 is in the set
}
```

Other operations might be implemented as algorithms in the standard library (`std::union`, `std::difference`... )

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::set`. See http://www.cplusplus.com for reference.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ there is nothing similarly integrated. Depending on your needs you might want to use bit flags and bitwise operations or the [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/) standard container (besides std::set, of course). If you are using C++Builder there is also a class that simulates Delphi sets - search System.hpp for something like BaseSet or SetBase or similar - I don't recall the exact name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a C++ STL `set` container class described on p. 491 of Stroustrup's TC++PL (Special Ed.).

Answer (score 0):

STL algorithm has the following
[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386172.aspx)

**set_difference** 
Unites all of the elements that belong to one sorted source range, but not to a second sorted source range, into a single, sorted destination range, where the ordering criterion may be specified by a binary predicate.

**set_intersection**
Unites all of the elements that belong to both sorted source ranges into a single, sorted destination range, where the ordering criterion may be specified by a binary predicate.

**set_symmetric_difference**
Unites all of the elements that belong to one, but not both, of the sorted source ranges into a single, sorted destination range, where the ordering criterion may be specified by a binary predicate.

**set_union**
Unites all of the elements that belong to at least one of two sorted source ranges into a single, sorted destination range, where the ordering criterion may be specified by a binary predicate.

Comment: These are algorithms that operate on ordered containers (on pairs of iterators to ordered elements to be precise), not the container itself.